# repeat an AsyncTask background operation periodically in android

Tags: android

i have an asyncTask, which i want to repeat the operation in background periodically, my asynctask is for example this:

```
new foo(someDetails).execute();
```

how i can achieve this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a TimerTask to call your assyncTask periocally.

TimerTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

here goes and example:

```
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //CALL YOUR ASSYNC TASK HERE.
            new foo(someDetails).execute();
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    //DELAY: the time to the first execution
    //PERIODICAL_TIME: the time between each execution of your task.
    timer.schedule(timerTask, DELAY,PERIODICAL_TIME);
```

Comment: I've read in many places that TimerTask is not a good technical choice. TimerTask is not running in UIThread and is not reliable. The consensus is to never use TimerTask: Source: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks

Answer (score 2):

use [**Handler**](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //your staff
                new foo(someDetails).execute();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + e);
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000);
        }
    };
handler.postDelayed(refresh, 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use **AlarmManager** and create a **Service** which will run **asyncTask**.

repeat your service using alarm manager.

Answer (score 1):

`Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

As Android docs says instead of TimerTask you should use AlarmManager or Handler.